# Redirect specific host from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need to redirect all https//panel.mysite.com to http://panel.mysite.com (HTTPS to HTTP) without affect any other redirections in my .htaccess. How do i proceed?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^panel\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```